# Android ignoring 'viewport' metatag

Tags: android, ios, viewport, metatag

I've included the 'viewport' metatag in the head of my webpage:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

The metatag works perfectly on iOS devices, but Android devices completely ignore it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to leave out the `user-scalable=no` argument. I've found Android tends to have trouble with that attribute and ignores the whole viewport tag when it finds something it dislikes.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11912